# AWS S3 Access Denied from EC2 and Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, permissions

I'm trying to get or list files from an S3 bucket.  The bucket is set up as no private access, has no specific permissions added.

I'm trying to access from EC2 configured with a role that has full S3 access, this worked before.

I'm also trying to access from Lambda, configured with a role that has full S3 access, this is new, and never worked before.

According to the IAM simulator this should be allowed.

This is an excerpt from my Lambda (python):

---

import json
import boto3
from datetime import datetime

def lambda_handler(event, context):

```
bucket = 'mybucketname' # this the name itself, no url or arn or anything

# check if file exists
s3client = boto3.client('s3')
key = 'mypath/' + 'anotherbitofpath' + '/' + 'index.html'
print(f"key = {key}")
objs = s3client.list_objects_v2(
    Bucket=bucket,
    Prefix=key
)
print(f"objs = {objs}")

if any([w.key == path_s3 for w in objs]):
    print("Exists!")
else:
    print("Doesn't exist")
```

---

many thanks

Comment: It turns out there was a horrendous typo in the code (now corrected), so the lambda function works ok now... retesting the ec2...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I implemented this exact use case. I can access S3 objects from a Lambda function. The only difference is I implemented my code in Java. This method that tags objects works perfectly in a Lambda function.

```
 private void tagExistingObject(S3Client s3, String bucketName, String key, String label, String LabelValue) {

        try {

           GetObjectTaggingRequest getObjectTaggingRequest = GetObjectTaggingRequest.builder()
                    .bucket(bucketName)
                    .key(key)
                    .build();

            GetObjectTaggingResponse response = s3.getObjectTagging(getObjectTaggingRequest);

            // Get the existing immutable list - cannot modify this list.
            List<Tag> existingList = response.tagSet();
            ArrayList<Tag> newTagList = new ArrayList(new ArrayList<>(existingList));

            // Create a new tag.
            Tag myTag = Tag.builder()
                    .key(label)
                    .value(LabelValue)
                    .build();

            // push new tag to list.
            newTagList.add(myTag);
            Tagging tagging = Tagging.builder()
                    .tagSet(newTagList)
                    .build();

            PutObjectTaggingRequest taggingRequest = PutObjectTaggingRequest.builder()
                    .key(key)
                    .bucket(bucketName)
                    .tagging(tagging)
                    .build();

            s3.putObjectTagging(taggingRequest);
            System.out.println(key + " was tagged with " + label);

        } catch (S3Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e.awsErrorDetails().errorMessage());
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
```

The role i use has full access to S3 and there are no issues performing S3 operations from a Lambda function.

Answer (score 1):

Update the bucket policy so that it specifies the ARN of the Lambda function's IAM role (execution role) as a Principal that has access to the action s3:GetObject. You can use a bucket policy similar to the following:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::YourAWSAccount:role/AccountARole"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:GetObjectVersion"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::YourBucketName/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```